# How does Inertia.js connect my Laravel backend on a domain name with my Vue.js project on another domain name?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

How does [Inertia.js](https://inertiajs.com/) connects my Laravel backend on a domain with my Vue.js project on another domain ?

Or am I trying to do something Inertia.js is not made for ?

Answer (score 0):

you answered your own question - Inertia is not for splitting the frontend from your backend. It's meant to couple the backend and frontend just like if you were to use blade.

From https://inertiajs.com:

> Build single-page apps, without building an API.
> Inertia.js lets you quickly build modern single-page React, Vue and Svelte apps using classic server-side routing and controllers.